# SonarQube doesn't show any issues with Maven project

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I was using Sonar two weeks ago and It worked fine.

Now, when I run sonar, without having changed the project, it shows me 0 issues, 0% technical debt, etc .. ( 20-30 issues were found two weeks ago and the project didn't have changed)

This is the result of mvn sonar:sonar

```
mvn sonar:sonar

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Golzio-Maumert-Rebouh-SillaPellicer 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) @ Golzio-Maumert-Rebouh-SillaPellicer ---
[INFO] SonarQube version: 5.1.1
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /Users/rebouhaymen/Documents/Projects/MinesAles/1A/ProjetGL/Golzio-Maumert-Rebouh-SillaPellicer/target/sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1.1
[INFO] [11:35:12.231] Load global repositories
[INFO] [11:35:12.368] Load global repositories (done) | time=140ms
[INFO] [11:35:12.370] Server id: 20150606110929
[INFO] [11:35:12.372] User cache: /Users/rebouhaymen/.sonar/cache
[INFO] [11:35:12.382] Install plugins
[INFO] [11:35:12.430] Install JDBC driver
[INFO] [11:35:12.437] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
[INFO] [11:35:13.627] Initializing Hibernate
[INFO] [11:35:15.128] Load project repositories
[INFO] [11:35:15.148] Load project repositories (done) | time=20ms
[INFO] [11:35:15.149] Load project settings
[INFO] [11:35:15.544] Load technical debt model
[INFO] [11:35:15.565] Apply project exclusions
[WARN] [11:35:15.843] SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.
[INFO] [11:35:15.844] -------------  Scan Golzio-Maumert-Rebouh-SillaPellicer
[INFO] [11:35:15.848] Load module settings
[INFO] [11:35:15.974] Load rules
[INFO] [11:35:16.027] Base dir: /Users/rebouhaymen/Documents/Projects/MinesAles/1A/ProjetGL/Golzio-Maumert-Rebouh-SillaPellicer
[INFO] [11:35:16.027] Working dir: /Users/rebouhaymen/Documents/Projects/MinesAles/1A/ProjetGL/Golzio-Maumert-Rebouh-SillaPellicer/target/sonar
[INFO] [11:35:16.028] Source paths: pom.xml, src/main/java
[INFO] [11:35:16.028] Test paths: src/test/java
[INFO] [11:35:16.028] Binary dirs: target/classes
[INFO] [11:35:16.028] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] [11:35:16.029] Index files
[INFO] [11:35:16.038] 0 files indexed
[INFO] [11:35:16.067] Sensor Lines Sensor
[INFO] [11:35:16.068] Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] [11:35:16.068] Sensor QProfileSensor
[INFO] [11:35:16.085] Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=17ms
[INFO] [11:35:16.085] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
[INFO] [11:35:16.094] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=9ms
[INFO] [11:35:16.094] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
[INFO] [11:35:16.108] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=14ms
[INFO] [11:35:16.108] Sensor VersionEventsSensor
[INFO] [11:35:16.122] Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=14ms
[INFO] [11:35:16.122] Sensor Maven dependencies
[INFO] [11:35:16.169] Sensor Maven dependencies (done) | time=47ms
[INFO] [11:35:16.169] Sensor SCM Sensor
[INFO] [11:35:16.169] No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.
[INFO] [11:35:16.169] Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] [11:35:16.169] Sensor CPD Sensor
[INFO] [11:35:16.169] Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] [11:35:16.170] No quality gate is configured.
[INFO] [11:35:16.215] Compare to previous analysis (2015-06-06)
[INFO] [11:35:16.221] Compare over 30 days (2015-05-07, analysis of Fri May 29 14:22:45 CEST 2015)
[INFO] [11:35:16.550] Execute decorators...
[INFO] [11:35:16.672] Store results in database
[INFO] [11:35:16.749] Analysis reports generated in 31ms, dir size=142 bytes
[INFO] [11:35:16.754] Analysis reports compressed in 5ms, zip size=518 bytes
[INFO] [11:35:16.782] Analysis reports sent to server in 28ms
[INFO] [11:35:16.782] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/projetGL:Golzio-Maumert-Rebouh-SillaPellicer
[INFO] [11:35:16.782] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.774 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-06-06T11:35:16+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/420M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
`
```

This is my pom.xml :

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>projetGL</groupId>
  <artifactId>Golzio-Maumert-Rebouh-SillaPellicer</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>Golzio-Maumert-Rebouh-SillaPellicer</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <!-- http://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning -->
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8</sonar.jdbc.url>
    <sonar.jdbc.driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driver>
    <sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
    <sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password>
    <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>Test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>projetGL.App</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

This is the server logs :

```
2015.06.07 14:28:28 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
2015.06.07 14:28:28 INFO   es[o.s.s.SearchServer]  Starting Elasticsearch[sonarqube] on port 9001
2015.06.07 14:28:33 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1433680102830] version[1.4.4], pid[40316], build[c88f77f/2015-02-19T13:05:36Z]
2015.06.07 14:28:33 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1433680102830] initializing ...
2015.06.07 14:28:33 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1433680102830] loaded [], sites []
2015.06.07 14:28:36 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1433680102830] initialized
2015.06.07 14:28:36 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1433680102830] starting ...
2015.06.07 14:28:41 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1433680102830] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/172.20.10.3:9001]}
2015.06.07 14:28:41 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1433680102830] sonarqube/dOoDg_ijSRqe9slU7KQPQQ
2015.06.07 14:28:44 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1433680102830] new_master [sonar-1433680102830][dOoDg_ijSRqe9slU7KQPQQ][MacBook-Pro-de-Rebouh.local][inet[/172.20.10.3:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1433680102830}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
2015.06.07 14:28:44 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1433680102830] started
2015.06.07 14:28:45 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1433680102830] recovered [6] indices into cluster_state
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=160m; support was removed in 8.0
2015.06.07 14:28:45 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
2015.06.07 14:28:45 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/rebouhaymen/Documents/sonarqube-5.1.1/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/Users/rebouhaymen/Documents/sonarqube-5.1.1/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /var/folders/30/vc9tg8r5173fr2lzwxd2ywdc0000gn/T/sq-process8400283793441720685properties
2015.06.07 14:28:51 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2015.06.07 14:28:51 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Webapp] Webapp directory: /Users/rebouhaymen/Documents/sonarqube-5.1.1/web
2015.06.07 14:28:51 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2015.06.07 14:28:51 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2015.06.07 14:28:52 INFO  web[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1433680102830] loaded [], sites []
2015.06.07 14:29:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.1.1 / 0a231d24c0f1e7ce1d200274b8e9bbe00f9f49fb
2015.06.07 14:29:03 INFO  web[o.s.c.p.Database] Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
2015.06.07 14:29:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: /Users/rebouhaymen/Documents/sonarqube-5.1.1
2015.06.07 14:29:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Install plugins
2015.06.07 14:29:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Core / 5.1.1 / 0a231d24c0f1e7ce1d200274b8e9bbe00f9f49fb
2015.06.07 14:29:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin Email notifications / 5.1.1 / 0a231d24c0f1e7ce1d200274b8e9bbe00f9f49fb
2015.06.07 14:29:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller] Deploy plugin English Pack / 5.1.1 / 0a231d24c0f1e7ce1d200274b8e9bbe00f9f49fb
2015.06.07 14:29:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploy Ruby on Rails applications
2015.06.07 14:29:04 INFO  web[o.s.j.s.AbstractDatabaseConnector] Initializing Hibernate
2015.06.07 14:29:11 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
2015.06.07 14:29:11 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2015.06.07 14:29:11 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index rules
2015.06.07 14:29:12 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index activeRules
2015.06.07 14:29:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
2015.06.07 14:29:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Cleaning quality gate conditions
2015.06.07 14:29:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDebtModel] Register technical debt model
2015.06.07 14:29:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
2015.06.07 14:29:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register quality profiles
2015.06.07 14:29:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters] Register measure filters
2015.06.07 14:29:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDashboards] Register dashboards
2015.06.07 14:29:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates] Register permission templates
2015.06.07 14:29:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RenameDeprecatedPropertyKeys] Rename deprecated property keys
2015.06.07 14:29:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index activities
2015.06.07 14:29:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index issues
2015.06.07 14:29:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index source lines
2015.06.07 14:29:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index users
2015.06.07 14:29:13 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer] Index views
2015.06.07 14:29:13 INFO  web[jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_25-b17 [darwin-x86_64]
2015.06.07 14:29:13 INFO  web[jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2015.06.07 14:29:14 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1433680102830] high disk watermark [10%] exceeded on [dOoDg_ijSRqe9slU7KQPQQ][sonar-1433680102830] free: 18.6gb[8%], shards will be relocated away from this node
2015.06.07 14:29:14 INFO   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1433680102830] high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes, rerouting shards
2015.06.07 14:29:21 INFO  web[jruby.rack] keeping custom (config.logger) Rails logger instance
2015.06.07 14:29:21 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2015.06.07 14:29:21 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2015.06.07 14:29:21 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2015.06.07 14:29:21 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
2015.06.07 14:29:44 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1433680102830] high disk watermark [10%] exceeded on [dOoDg_ijSRqe9slU7KQPQQ][sonar-1433680102830] free: 18.6gb[8%], shards will be relocated away from this node
2015.06.07 14:30:09 INFO  web[o.s.s.c.ComputationService] Analysis of project projetGL:Golzio-Maumert-Rebouh-SillaPellicer (report 9) (done) | time=317ms
2015.06.07 14:30:14 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1433680102830] high disk watermark [10%] exceeded on [dOoDg_ijSRqe9slU7KQPQQ][sonar-1433680102830] free: 18.6gb[8%], shards will be relocated away from this node
2015.06.07 14:30:44 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1433680102830] high disk watermark [10%] exceeded on [dOoDg_ijSRqe9slU7KQPQQ][sonar-1433680102830] free: 18.6gb[8%], shards will be relocated away from this node
2015.06.07 14:30:44 INFO   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1433680102830] high disk watermark exceeded on one or more nodes, rerouting shards
2015.06.07 14:31:14 WARN   es[o.e.c.r.a.decider]  [sonar-1433680102830] high disk watermark [10%] exceeded on [dOoDg_ijSRqe9slU7KQPQQ][sonar-1433680102830] free: 18.6gb[8%], shards will be relocated away from this node
```

Comment: Can you edit to include your *entire* pom.xml? It looks like SonarQube can't find your source files.

Comment: It's now included :]

Comment: Well *something* strange is going on. Does your project compile under Maven? Is any part of `src/main/java` a symlink?

Comment: Can you include the "installed" plugins on your SonarQube?

Comment: Where can I get the plugins installed ?

Comment: Settings - System - Update Center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java plugin is not installed. You probably forgot to copy the directory extensions/plugins when upgrading to 5.1.1.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what I need to do please ?

Comment: The Java plugin must be installed on server.

Comment: It's a local server. And I have java installed

Comment: So I confirm that the Java plugin is not installed.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by the Java plugin ?
Isn't the <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins> line from the pom.xml ?

Comment: Not at all. SonarQube supports analysis of many different languages (Javascript, Swift, Cobol and... Java). Each language is handled by a SonarQube plugin, to not be mixed with Maven plugin.
Plugin doc: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin

You can use Update Center web console (Settings -> System -> Update Center -> Available Plugins) to download and install plugins.

Comment: Hum I have a mac so I don't have this Settings/System etc ..
But when I go to the java website, it tell me I have the last version of Java
Also, I noticed that I don't use settings.xml from my maven project, only the pom.xml

Comment: Sorry but you mix everything. It seems that you are not aware that SonarQube allows to install some plugins. Open http://localhost:9000, log in as administrator, click on Settings, then System, then Update Center. If you still do not succeed, please read the documentation for more details.

Comment: Hoo it works. But It's strange that it works a few weeks ago, without doing what you told me. Thanks you