# No SCM was detected

Tags: jenkins

```
10:43:16.645 INFO  - 0 files indexed
10:43:16.646 INFO  - 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
10:43:16.666 INFO  - Quality profile for java: Sonar way
10:43:21.609 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
10:43:21.610 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=1ms
10:43:21.610 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
10:43:21.610 INFO  - No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.
10:43:21.611 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=1ms
10:43:21.611 INFO  - Sensor XmlFileSensor
```

Comment: what plugins to be insatalled/ sonar properties should be added for this

Comment: Your configuration is what, how, ...? Dropping just a few lines of a build's Console Output is a bit sparse.

Comment: ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
atorg.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91) atorg.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
atorg.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
atorg.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)atorg.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
a

Comment: we have integrated sonar with jenkins to generate sonar report when i do build it gets checout of files but, files are not analysing later.

Comment: 02:54:53.999 INFO  - 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
02:54:54.160 INFO  - Quality profile for java: Sonar way
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 29.091s
Final Memory: 10M/133M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
a1)

Comment: installed all plugins
sonar-android-plugin-1.1.jar
sonar-csharp-plugin-5.3.1.jar
sonar-flex-plugin-2.3.jar
sonar-github-plugin-1.4.0.699.jar
sonar-groovy-plugin-1.4.jar
sonar-java-plugin-4.5.0.8398.jar
sonar-javascript-plugin-2.14.jar
sonar-jproperties-plugin-2.5.jar
sonar-ldap-plugin-2.1.0.507.jar
sonar-php-plugin-2.9.2.1744.jar
sonar-rci-plugin-1.0.1.jar
sonar-scm-clearcase-plugin-1.1.jar
sonar-scm-cvs-plugin-1.0.jar
sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.2.jar
sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.4.0.522.jar
sonar-scm-tfvc-plugin-2.1.2.jar
sonar-sonargraph-integration-2.0.1.jar
sonar-sonargraph-plugi

Comment: sonarqube - 6.0
sonar-runner- 2.4
please, let me know if any info needed?

Comment: 02:54:53.985 INFO  - 546 files indexed
02:54:53.999 INFO  - 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
02:54:54.160 INFO  - Quality profile for java: Sonar way
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 29.091s
Final Memory: 10M/133M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Please add the information to your question (via the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42358586/edit) below it). The comment formatting is a bit unconvenient.

Comment: Sorry, for comments which posted in break sentence. Its becoz of exceed in length. Any how got resolved the issue. Thanks for concern

Answer (score 0):

See "[SonarQube doesn't show any issues with Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30682845/6309)", and check your Sonar server:  log in as administrator, click on `Settings`, then `System`, then `Update Center`.

Check if the [Sonar Java plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJava) is installed. If not, click on  `Available Plugins` to download and install it.