# c c++ code analysis No SCM was detected

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am trying to analyse my code .
Code is getting analysed successfully but there are few warnings:

**INFO: No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.**

And on web page my code shows that, it is passed but i am not able to see code.
As well as in all reports "0" defect it is showing .

Comment: You should provide much more info. What is the SonarQube version you use and what are the plugins you installed? Also have a quick look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358586/no-scm-was-detected) SO question.

Comment: my property file:sonar.projectKey=bl_rnc_rif38240h4221
sonar.projectName=BL_RNC_RIF38240H4221

sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.projectBaseDir=/view/mmallu_sonar_build_test

sonar.sources=ccase_rnccn/build_cn/src

sonar.analysis.mode=publish

sonar.working.directory=/users/rnclb/SCANNER/workdir/

sonar.scm.provider=clearcase
sonar.language=c++